Animate Matplotlib-Seaborn plot using blit
There are already multiple post about animated plot using Matplotlib and how to improve performance using blit technique, but I couldn't find a way to animate a Seaborn plot using blit. So far I've the code below that is heavily inspired from here Redrawing Seaborn Figures for Animations
I know that in order to use the blit technique, my animate method should return a list of the Artist to redraw, I tried to "bruteforce" it by passing all the children for each axis of my plot but apparently I get the following error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_get_view'
So my question, where can I find the Artist I need to return in order for the blit technique to work ? I'm afraid that the only way is to look at the Seaborn source code as the documentation doesn't mentions those kind of use case at all...
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import seaborn as sns
import random

g = sns.JointGrid()

x,y = [0], [0]

x_lim = (-2,2)
y_lim = (-2,2)

def prep_axis(g, x_lim, y_lim):
    g.ax_joint.clear()
    g.ax_joint.set_xlim(x_lim)
    g.ax_joint.set_ylim(y_lim)

    g.ax_marg_x.clear()
    g.ax_marg_x.set_xlim(x_lim)

    g.ax_marg_y.clear()
    g.ax_marg_y.set_ylim(y_lim)

    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_x.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_y.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_x.yaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_majorticklines(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_y.xaxis.get_minorticklines(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_x.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(g.ax_marg_y.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

def animate(frame):
    global g, x_lim, y_lim
    prep_axis(g, x_lim, y_lim)

    x.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
    y.append(random.uniform(-1, 1))
    sns.kdeplot(x=x, y=y, ax=g.ax_joint)
    sns.kdeplot(x=x, linewidth=2, ax=g.ax_marg_x)
    sns.kdeplot(y=y, linewidth=2, ax=g.ax_marg_y)
    #return (*g.ax_joint.get_children(), *g.ax_marg_x.get_children(), *g.ax_marg_y.get_children())

anim = FuncAnimation(
    g.figure,
    animate, 
    interval = 50, 
    blit = False, #True
    repeat = True
) 

plt.show()


Probably blitting won't work here, as you are recalculating the curves at each step, and clearing and redrawing multiple subplots. Even if you would rewrite everything via reusing matplotlib primitives, blitting wouldn't win a lot of speedon modern PCs. (Also, if speed would be a concern, using Python lists with append() is unnecessarily quadratic in time.)

Yeah I was afraid it wouldn't be that simple. I think I'm gonna try to find a python library that can do fastKDE and use the standard matplotlib scatter with blitting. Maybe I'll need to do the fastKDE on a separate process to improve efficiency. Btw the list append() here was just as an example but isn't present in my project.

Yes you right, it is a calculating speed issue, my x and y values contains each 2000 datapoint, I'm not sure this can be considered very large. Ideally I would like to be able to compute the 2D Density map with a refresh rate of 10Hz. I should try to look for GPU accelerated solution I think.

2000 data points isn't that many.  But the way Seaborn's 2D kdeplot works, building on matplotlib's contour plot, will always be too slow for fluid animation. You need to save your animation to a file (mpeg) and then display that file at the desired speed. Also note that the animation will have some jumps, as the "height" lines will be recalculated at each step, representing different heights in subsequent frames.
